# Is there any way to Prevent service.exe not to corrupt when unexpected shut down occur

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0

I have a WCF service which is running on my server but sometimes when unexpected shut down corrupt the file and then I have to repair the service again. Please suggest me any way to prevent the corruption of file.

Comment: On a wider scope, you may consider to "simply" design for it to crash _always_. I.e. just assume there is no such thing as a clean exit and always provide (automatic) means to have it repair/heal itself on next startup (consider [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/191059/) for some background on the topic). In your case specifically, what do you mean by "corrupts the file"? The executable file of your service? Some data file?

Comment: Thanks for your help. the service.exe.Config file got corrupt sometime

Comment: That's somewhat strange. _Normally_ the service.exe.config file would not be updated by application (albeit possible; APIs do exist to do that). Do you actively update the configuration file from within your service?

Comment: Thanks for helping. I found the issue was that my app was updating the service.exe.config file on every startup. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. You might want to turn that comment to an answer to your own question and thereby close it.

Comment: how can i close the question?

Comment: Post an answer to it yourself, than accept that answer. [see here also](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)